# How to load through RequireJS a non-AMD script that manipulates the Global Namespace?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, javascript-namespaces

I have some Javascript modules and their dependencies declared and organized with RequireJS, and it works like a charm. However, one specific module calls a function defined into the Global Namespace by a legacy non-AMD script - which I'm loading before RequireJS. The problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize this function.

They do recognize, though, functions defined inside this non-AMD script when they reside in a specific namespace (such as $ for JQuery).

This is how I'm loading them:

```
<script src="scripts/legacyscript.js"></script>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

And this my main.js, consider that module.stuff() will call internally the Global Namespace function:

```
require(["module"], function(module) {
    module.stuff();
});
```

I don't get any problems when the page loads, but they show up when I run something from the module that happens to depend on that Global Namespace function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getType'
```

Those scripts were made externally and I'm not supposed to change anything in them. Any thoughts?

Comment: The error message shows that the global on which you call `getType` is defined but does not have a `getType` method. Did you try dumping that global to the console to see what value it has? Maybe it is getting clobbered by something else.

Comment: Sounds interesting, apparently Object.getType is found when I run it from the console.